# MySQL container stalls at "X Plugin ready for connections" after docker-compose up

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to start up a simple MySQL docker container.

The yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  local:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3316:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
```

When I run *docker-compose up*, the process stalls at:

```
local_1  | 2020-02-15T21:33:02.320280Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Comment: When you say “stalls”, what do you mean?  Does it also say before this that it’s listening on the normal port 3306?  What do you expect to see after this line?

Comment: @DavidMaze this is the output I get just before "local_1  | 2020-02-15T21:33:02.242546Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL." It is more than possible I just don't understand how this is supposed to work. What I was expecting was for the process to complete and allow me to use the command line again but it just hangs there. Is this normal? If so, how do I get the command line back without having to do CONTROL+Z?

Comment: That’s normal, then; `docker-compose` will keep running until all of the managed containers exit.  Adding a `-d` option will get you a command prompt back immediately.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you! That's exactly what I needed to know.